# Replace a string, but only when it is the last occurance of that string before a specific line

Tags: sed

I am converting a custom markup language to TeX.

I have a file like this:

```
\macro{stuff}
{more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}
these are extra lines
another extra line
there can be any number of extra lines
e

\macro{yet more stuff stuff}
{even more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}
this is extra
this is extra too
e
```

I need the result to be this:

```
\macro{stuff}
{more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}{
these are extra lines
another extra line
there can be any number of extra lines
}

\macro{yet more stuff stuff}
{even more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}{
this is extra
this is extra too
}
```

Notice `e` is by itself on a line, indicating the end of a set of data, it simply gets replaced with a closing bracket.

I could simply use this:

```
sed -i 's/^e$/}/g' file.tex
```

Resulting in this:

```
\macro{stuff}
{more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}
these are extra lines
another extra line
there can be any number of extra lines
}

\macro{yet more stuff stuff}
{even more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}
this is extra
this is extra too
}
```

The problem is, I also need a matching starting bracket to surround this extra text before the `e`.

One way to think of it is:

1. Replace every occurrence of `}`.
2. But only if that occurrence is at the end of the line.
3. And only if that it is the last occurrence appearing before an `e` appearing completely by itself.

This is the closest I can figure, not sure how to match across any number of lines not containing more matches of `}$`:

```
sed -i 's/}$\n.*\n.*\n.*\n^e$/}{&}/g' file.tex
```

How can I wrap that final extra text inside `{` and `}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to do this using `awk` using an empty `RS`. Here is a `gnu-awk` solution:

```sh
awk -v RS= '{sub(/.*}/, "&{"); sub(/\ne$/, "\n}"); ORS=RT} 1' file

\macro{stuff}
{more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}{
these are extra lines
another extra line
there can be any number of extra lines
}

\macro{yet more stuff stuff}
{even more stuff}
{yet other stuff}
{some stuff}{
this is extra
this is extra too
}
```

Or in any version of `awk`:

```
awk -v RS= '{sub(/.*}/, "&{"); sub(/\ne$/, "\n}\n")} 1' file
```

Comment: [Had to look this up](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp-Patterns). :)  RS is "null string, in which case records are separated by runs of blank lines." It puts it in *paragraph* mode. Now it makes perfect sense, lol

Answer (score 1):

Not as short or elegant as @anubhava's `awk` solution, but as an exercise I implemented the same in GNU `sed`.

```
 sed -n '/^e$/{ z; x; s/.*}/&{/; s/$/\n}/; p; d; }; /^$/d; H; ${ H; x; p; }' file
```

Breaking it out -
`/^e$/{ z; x; s/.*}/&{/; s/$/\n}/; p; d; };` by component...
`/^e$/{ ... }` performs this list of actions on a line with just `e`:
`z` is a GNU option that empties the pattern space.
`x` e`x`changes the pattern and hold spaces.
`s/.*}/&{/` adds an open paren after the last close paren in the block.
`s/$/\n}/` adds a newline and `}` where the `e` was.
`p` will `p`rint the pattern space, and `d` will `d`elete the record and move on.

`/^$/d` removes the empty records between.
`H` says `H`old (append) the pattern space record onto the hold space, so that we accumulate the block until we hit the next `e` terminator line, or the end.

`${ H; x; p; }`  just makes sure to print any record(s) after the last `e`.
Skip that if you don't care, or if you know there shouldn't be any.

If you aren't using GNU `sed`, it would look a bit different, lol

Answer (score 1):

With the presented input, match anything between `}` up until a `e` on the line - with GNU sed with `-z` option:

```
sed -Ez 's/([^}]*)\ne(\n|$)/{\1\n}\2/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where I like to use `tac`

```sh
tac file | awk '
  /^e$/ {print "}"; p=1; next}
  p && /^\{/ {print $0 "{"; p=0; next}
  1
' | tac
```

That awk command adds the open brace on the **first** line starting with a brace following the replacement of `e`.

When I see questions like "do something for the *last* X", I think "reverse the file and do something for the *first* X, then re-reverse the file

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable.

The script `script.ed`

```
g?^e$?s/.*/}/\
?^{.*?s/$/{/
,p
Q
```

---

```
ed -s file.txt < script.ed
```

---

In one line, with quoting syntax from bash `$''`

```
printf '%s\n' $'g?^e$?s/.*/}/\\\n?^{.*?s/$/{/' ,p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/}\n\([^{]\)/}{\n\1/;s/\ne$/\n}/;P;D' file
```

There are two instances where a substitution is needed:

1. When a line ends in `}` but the next line does not begin with `{`.
2. When a line only contains `e`.

By opening a two line window using the `N`, `P` and `D` commands both conditions can be catered for.

The first by appending a `{` to the first line of the window.

The second by replacing the `e` by a `}`.